# Number Pattern Printing in Java

Tags: java

I'm newbie to programming. So as an exercise, I'm trying to print a number pattern like below

```
   4
  34 
 234 
1234
```

I tried the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int n =4;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            for (int j = i; j <= n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            int num = 4;

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(num);
                num--;
            }
            System.out.println("");

        }

    }
```

but it is printing in this way.

```
    4
   43
  432
 4321
```

I think, I have to decrement the value before printing. Please correct me if i'm wrong. But I'm stuck here. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the pattern you want to get:

```
   4
  34
 234
1234
```

When you describe the pattern in words, it could look like this:

- line 1 has 3 spaces, and then the digit 4
- line 2 has 2 spaces, and then the digits 3 and 4
- line 3 has 1 space, and then the digits 2 to 4
- line 4 has 0 spaces, and then the digits 1 to 4

There is already some kind of pattern here. The last two lines look remarkably similar. Let's see whether the first two lines can be brought into the same form:

- line 1 has 3 space(s), and then the digits 4 to 4
- line 2 has 2 space(s), and then the digits 3 to 4
- line 3 has 1 space(s), and then the digits 2 to 4
- line 4 has 0 space(s), and then the digits 1 to 4

Now that looks good. The next step is to change the wording to depend on the given line:

- line i has (4 - i) space(s), and then the digits (4 - i + 1) to 4

I took care not to say 5 instead of the 4 + 1, so that the 4 is still visible. Let's give this 4 another name:

- line i has (max - i) space(s), and then the digits (max - i + 1) to max

Now you should be able to translate this instruction into Java code.

Comment: I am not a fan of the other answers. They are basically doing the OPs homework. This is a great answer for any new developers trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one inner for-loop.
I use the ternary operator (also called elvis-operator because `?:`) to decide whether to print the number or a blank space:

```
int n = 7;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        System.out.print(j > n-i ? j : " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It prints

```
      7
     67
    567
   4567
  34567
 234567
1234567
```

Answer (score -1):

You actually only need one nested loop in this situation:

```
int n = 4;
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (j < i) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

So loop from `0` to `n` and either print a space, or print the number if the inner counter is less than `i`.

**Output:**

```
   4
  34 
 234 
1234
```